# Multiple optional URL arguments in Django 2+

Tags: django, django-urls, django-2.0

I am trying to implement multiple URL patterns pointing to one Class Based View in my django 2+ app.

My urls:

```
path('<slug:slug>', views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name='show'),
path('<slug:slug>/<str:status>', views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name='show'),
path('<slug:slug>/<str:status>/<uuid:application>', views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name='show'),
path('<slug:slug>/<uuid:application>', views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name='show'),
```

Let's say that "`ABC12`" is my slug here. **What is my expected behaviour**:

- when user enters */ABC12*: view's kwargs status and application are Nones, slug is **ABC12**
- when user enters */ABC12/new*: view's kwargs status is "**new**" and application is None, slug is **ABC12**
- when user enters */ABC12/new/6eba5dbf-220b-4913-a359-f93fab3153d1*: view's kwargs status is "**new**" and application kwarg is "**6eba5dbf-220b-4913-a359-f93fab3153d1**", slug is **ABC12**
- when user enters */ABC12/6eba5dbf-220b-4913-a359-f93fab3153d1*: view's kwargs status is **None** and application kwarg is "**6eba5dbf-220b-4913-a359-f93fab3153d1**", slug is **ABC12**

however, when I type url:
/ABC12/6eba5dbf-220b-4913-a359-f93fab3153d1

kwargs are:

> {'slug': 'ABC12', 'status': '6eba5dbf-220b-4913-a359-f93fab3153d1'}

(I've expected that there should be not status kwarg, and 'application' kwarg should be "6eba5dbf-220b-4913-a359-f93fab3153d1").

How can I achieve this? I don't want to end up with multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because this `'6eba5dbf-220b-4913-a359-f93fab3153d1'` uuid is satisfying 2nd pattern of your URL i.e

```
path('<slug:slug>/<str:status>', views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name='show'),
```

One thing you can do to solve it is to rearrange the sequence of URL patterns, keep your last `<uuid:application>` pattern on 2nd number.

```
path('<slug:slug>', views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name='show1'),
# keep this here
path('<slug:slug>/<uuid:application>', views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name='show2'),
path('<slug:slug>/<str:status>', views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name='show3'),
path('<slug:slug>/<str:status>/<uuid:application>', views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name='show4'),
```

> Also don't use same name for url patterns

**UPDATE**

> **str** - Matches any non-empty string, excluding the path separator, '/'.
>   This is the default if a converter isn’t included in the expression.

So if you are willing to parse `uuid` you should keep it above from `str` pattern, if your URL patterns are similar other than arg type

On the other hand, `uuid` will only parse the string formatted like `'6eba5dbf-220b-4913-a359-f93fab3153d1'`

> **uuid** - Matches a formatted UUID. To prevent multiple URLs from mapping
>   to the same page, dashes must be included and letters must be
>   lowercase. For example, 075194d3-6885-417e-a8a8-6c931e272f00. Returns
>   a UUID instance.

[**`Read the docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)

Comment: Why is it satisfying 2nd url pattern? So what is the purpose of argument types in urls, if its UUID not string?
EDIT: changing <str:status> to <slug:status> worked for me, now everything is working just fine

Comment: @dease Check my update, let me know if this fixed your issue

Comment: @dease If you want to keep it `str`, you need to rearrange the URL sequence. can you verify this answer? by changing the `str` to `slug` solved for you but this is not the idol solution.